# IndentationError: expected an indented block in python (using hard tabs)

Tags: python, tabs, atom-editor

I have checked and double checked that my code it properly using tabs for indentation instead of spaces that look like tabs. I'm using the atom code editor on Max OS X. My settings regarding tabs are as follows:

- Soft tabs are unchecked
- Tab size is set to 4
- Tab type is set to hard

Here is my code:

```
#Password Cracker test program
#Program written by Zach Hofmeister, ported to Python
#READ THE README BEFORE USING ANY OF MY CODE!!!

#Below variable saves the password entered by the user. Only compared to a complete password to simulate brute-force cracking.
userPassword = raw_input("Enter a 4 digit password for the computer to guess. Only Upper/Lower case letters and numbers.") + ""

#The following variable contains an array of all the possible characters that can be present.
possibleCharacters = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']

#The default computer guess.
computerGuess = 'AAAA'

#Establishes that the computer has not correctly guessed the password, will be changed when password is discovered.
correctGuess = False

#The following variable keeps track of how many guesses it takes for the computer to crack the password.
totalGuesses = 0

#The following variable keeps track of what character is currently being tested.
i = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

#Function that compares the current guess to the user input. Notice that the password isn't guessed letter by letter, the whole 4 character guess is generated.
def checkPassword(passwordGuess):
    if (passwordGuess == userPassword):
        print "Your password is " + computerGuess + "."
        print "Took " + totalGuesses + " tries to guess your password."
    else:
        #print "Guessing again."

#Function that creates the current guess and compares it to the actual password.
def charGuess(charNumberDigit):
    computerGuess = computerGuess[0:charNumberDigit - 1] + possibleCharacters[i[charNumberDigit - 1]] + computerGuess[charNumberDigit:end]
    checkPassword(computerGuess)
    if (charNumberDigit != 4):
        i[charNumberDigit] = 0
    i[charNumberDigit - 1] += 1
    totalGuesses += 1

#The loop that tells the computer to try a guess
while (computerGuess != userPassword):
    while (i[3] <= 61 && computerGuess != userPassword):
        charGuess(4)
        while (i[2] <= 61 && i[3] == 61 && computerGuess != userPassword):
            charGuess(3)
            while (i[1] <= 61 && i[2] == 61 && computerGuess != userPassword):
                charGuess(2)
                while (i[0] <= 61 && i[1] === 61 && computerGuess != userPassword):
                    charGuess(1)
```

By the way, I have read other posts on this problem and they did not solve my problem, as (as far as I know) I am properly using tabs and not a mix of tabs and spaces.

Comment: The issue is in your else block. You commented out the next line, so it thinks that the function underneath `charGuess` is part of the else block. You could write `pass` under the else block if you don't want anything to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python there always has to be something in a code block. You have commented out the else block in your checkPassword function.

```
def checkPassword(passwordGuess):
    if (passwordGuess == userPassword):
        print "Your password is " + computerGuess + "."
        print "Took " + totalGuesses + " tries to guess your password."
    else:
        #print "Guessing again."
```

You can use the [pass](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements) statement if you don't want to do anything:

```
else:
    pass
```